# How do you get out of chamber 3?

Tags: portal

So, I'm in Test Chamber 003 of Portal 1, and am trying to get into a door, but I can't reach it. I have to go down a set of stairs and then there is no way up... How can I get up there?

[image]

Comment: I assume this is Test Chamber 002, did you wait for a portal to appear by you and go through it? Then jump off of the ledge and take what is making those *strange* portals.

Comment: its actually Test Chamber 003 @Krazer, just figured it out.

Comment: This is one of the chambers where you really need to come up with the solution yourself :)

Comment: Ironically you unspoilered my solution when I was trying to give hints first @badp.  :P

Comment: @JeffMercado if it's the whole point of your answer it mustn't be spoiler protected. If somebody visits this page, it's because they've _given up already_ and _want this spoiled_ for them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on where you are standing in that screenshot, there should be an orange portal already in place to your right.  You can only shoot blue portals so how would you get a portal on the other side so you can use the one that you can already reach?

Just shoot a blue portal to the other side and walk through the orange portal that is nearby.

Answer (score 17):

The point of this test is teaching you that the two portals are functionally equivalent: you are not going to always enter the blue portal and leave the orange portal.

This time, you instead need to enter the *orange* portal and leave the *blue* portal by placing the blue portal by the door.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember the game correctly, there's an orange portal behind you, high up on the wall. You need to get across this gap. You can't reach the orange portal to go through it to the other side, but you can use momentum to launch yourself through it.

Put the blue portal on the ground at your feet. Jump through it. OMG FLYING! Now, before you land, shoot the blue portal right where you're going to hit the ground. Suddenly, FLYING REALLY FAST. You should be going fast enough to launch yourself completely over the gap, onto the ledge on the other side.

This process is referred to as "flinging", and becomes very useful later in the game.

Comment: I don't think that's the point in the game where you learn about the flinging.  IIRC, you had _just_ gotten the blue portal gun so that's a bit advanced at that point.

Comment: @JeffMercado, agreed. This shouldn't be the accepted answer, although flinging is definitely something useful to know.

Comment: My bad - I had misinterpreted where he was in the game.